# Send a custom email when a specific order item meta is empty in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I use this code for get meta in some product.

```
$meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data($hideprefix = '_', $include_all = false );
foreach ($meta_data as $dato){
$datoo = (array) $dato;
$mess .= $datoo['display_key'].': ' .$datoo['value']. '<br>' ;

}
```

one of these key is "Nome File".

Now i need to send a mail when this meta is empty in all the products.

I need to modify this code but i don't know how...

```
    // On order completed status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'send_a_custom_email', 20, 1 );
//add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'send_a_custom_email', 20, 1 );
function send_a_custom_email( $order_id ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); // The WC_Product object

    // Get the parent product ID for product variations for product categories
    $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if (  has_term( array(115, 117, 555, 556, 789, 786, 554), 'product_cat', $the_id ) ) {
```

can someone help me?

Comment: yes is an error for test. i have delete the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the the way to a custom email when specific order item meta data is missing (or empty):

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'send_a_custom_email', 20, 2 );
// add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'send_a_custom_email', 20, 2 );
function send_a_custom_email( $order_id, $order ) {
    $product_ids = array(); // Initializing
    
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $meta_data  = $item->get_meta('Nome File'); // Get order item meta data
        
        if( empty($meta_data) ) {
            $product_ids[] = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
        }
    }
    if ( ! empty($product_ids) ) {
        $recipient = 'name@email.com'; // Set email recipient
        $subject   = sprintf( __('Order #%d: Has missing item meta data'), $order_id );
        $content   = sprintf( __('On Order #%d, purchased products %s have missing meta data'), $order_id, implode(', ', $product_ids) );
        wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $content ); // Send email
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec the code works only if a update the order.
The meta is upload by a plugin and run later the snippet.
So when the snippet start the meta is empty but if i upload the order the meta is full and all works fine.
can i delay the snippet? I have try with prioritis but don't works.

Comment: You just need to run this code after "The meta is upload by a plugin"

can you give me some hint?

Comment: The code line stores the product id (or the variation Id) in an array that I use in the email subject…

Comment: loic you are ever the best!

Comment: @AndreaRighi I can't really say, as I don't know how your plugin works to update order item meta data… Is better that you ask a new question for that, Including a link to this answer code, providing the related code from your plugin that update item meta data and some explanations.

Comment: thanks! I will try alone and if i can't resolve i post the question! thanks again!